# Sqoop Import: Command --password: command not found, --table: command not found

Tags: mysql, azure, hadoop, sqoop

I have to write a scoop import script which pulls certain columns from a data la_crime only from the year 2016
My script is below"

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://XXXXXXXXXXX \
--driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \
--username XXXX \
--password XXXX \
--table la_crime \
--query "SELECT DR_NUMBER,DATE_REPORTED,DATE_OCCURED,TIME_OCCURED,AREA_ID,AREA_N AME,REPORTING_DISTRICT,CRIME_CODE,CRIME_CODE_DESC,VICTIM_AGE,VICTIM _GENDER,VICTIM_DESCENT,ADDRESS,CROSS_STREET,AUTO_ID FROM la_crime WHERE\$YEAR=2016\
--target-dir /user/sqoop_script \
-m 1
```

Could you tell me if my code is wrong somewhere? What changes do I have to make?

Answer (score 0):

**You may use the following syntax to import:**

sqoop import \

--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/yourdatabase \

--driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \

--username XXXX \

--password XXXX \

--table la_crime \

--query ‘SELECT DR_NUMBER,DATE_REPORTED,DATE_OCCURED,TIME_OCCURED,AREA_ID,AREA_N AME,REPORTING_DISTRICT,CRIME_CODE,CRIME_CODE_DESC,VICTIM_AGE,VICTIM _GENDER,VICTIM_DESCENT,ADDRESS,CROSS_STREET,AUTO_ID FROM la_crime WHERE $YEAR=2016' \

--target-dir /user/sqoop_script \

-m 1

For more details, refer “[Sqoop User Guide](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.1-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#_syntax)”.

Answer (score 0):

The command you're trying has some things wrong in the `query` option, first you need to close the double quotes at the end. Second, it seems weird to me that you're using a variable to specify the column to filter the year.

And third, if you use the `query` option it's mandatory to include the `$CONDITIONS` token and since you're using double quotes to issuing the query you need to `\$CONDITIONS` instead of just `$CONDITIONS` to disallow your shell from treating it as a shell variable.

Also, if you're using the `query` option you shouldn't use the `table` option.

I think this would be the command you're looking for:

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://XXXXXXXXXXX \
--driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \
--username XXXX \
--password XXXX \
--query "SELECT DR_NUMBER,DATE_REPORTED,DATE_OCCURED,TIME_OCCURED,AREA_ID,AREA_N AME,REPORTING_DISTRICT,CRIME_CODE,CRIME_CODE_DESC,VICTIM_AGE,VICTIM _GENDER,VICTIM_DESCENT,ADDRESS,CROSS_STREET,AUTO_ID FROM la_crime WHERE YEAR = 2016 AND $CONDITIONS" \
--target-dir /user/sqoop_script \
-m 1
```